# How to point to n'th char from string in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

When I iterate over a vector using an int (say i), I can easily say:

```
vector<string> V;
V[i][g]
```

in which (int) g is the g'th character of the string in V[i]

When I am in a loop and want to keep iterating although I will delete items (from V) on the run, I want to make use of:

```
vector<string>::iterator it;
```

and then, I thought, the g'th character of V[i] would - in the loop - be:

```
for (it = V.begin() ; it != V.end() ; it++)
    *it[g]
```

or, more logically in my eyes:

```
    it[g]
```

bit neither work... Can anyone tell me how to get the g'th char of V[i] in this iterator-using variant?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? There may well be a better solution than what you are currently attempting (one involving using a standard [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)).

Comment: I want to compare the g'th character of V[i] to another character... But I can't seem to get it...

Comment: Let's say V[i]  = "ABCD", how do I point to, say, the C in this string...

Comment: `V[i][2]` would give you `'C'`.

Comment: Yes but I would like this in terms of iterator it... As there is no i, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = V.begin(); it!=V.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;       // whole string
        std::cout << (*it)[2] << std::endl;  // third letter only
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!!